# what to do? I am really stuck...attaching php to java's struts

Tags: java, php, javascript, html

I am really confused what to do...So there is a software named Service desk plus which is a network monitoring tool written in Java...It uses struts...I need to attach some php scripts that I have to the software.The software runs in a browser. What the issue is that the only way I see to attach my php scripts to the tool is to modify its .jsp files and their html to add an extra navigation bar that will be attached to my ***php scripts AND lead to my website*** however this goes against the copyright laws and such...So I was looking forward to help help from the professionals and experienced programmers here on what to do...I don't know how but a solution I have is that when I go to a special link on the software such as dashboard.do my php script will automatically trigger and my website will pop up as a pop up...I really have no ideas and I am clueless on this..Help!

Below I have done my best to show you what I am trying to do through image. If you require any more clarification or explanation please comment it and I will add it ASAP[image: Possible Solution but don't know how].

Comment: You are trying to take an existing web application and add your pop up to it without the original application owner's permission?

Comment: @Nivas Assuming he's talking about modifying *his copy* of the software, what would be intrinsically wrong with that? When you download WordPress, Drupal, vBulletin, or virtually any other website software, it's *expected* you will make code changes without asking anyone permission. Unless there's a EULA attached forbidding it, that's even your legal right under the doctrine of first sale... the copyright holder's rights to control a copy end after that copy is sold. In this case, there is such a legal agreement, but your comment seemed to suppose a world where that isn't even required.

Comment: @Dan Grossman, valid point. But he clearly says: _the only way I see [...] is to modify its .jsp files and their html to add an extra navigation bar [...] however this goes against the copyright laws and such_

Comment: @Nivas He's mistaken there, though. It does not go against copyright law at all. Copyright does not forbid anyone from modifying their legally obtained copy of any work. Only by looking up this software, attempting to purchase it and finding the legal agreement you must read before buying, was I able to find that he had agreed not to modify the code. That's nothing to do with copyright, it's just a contract.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing up my confusion. I didnt know that I was allowed to modify my copy of the software and it wouldn't go against copy rights etc. Thanks a lot for that, I WAS mistaken :) Do you have any possible solution as to how I can find the .jsp thats generating the html? I know the name of it but I can't find out where it is...I tried searching program files but I couldn't find any .jsp inside except 3. Through the struct-config.xml I was able to find the name of the files generating the html. I can't find them in the program files and folders though.

Comment: Jeff, it's like you're selectively reading only what you want to see. Both of my comments say that you're not allowed to modify the software, but that the reason is not copyright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe write a javascript that inserts the html link to the site and include that js file as part of the application headers. it would still require that you modify their code, but it would be a simple change to include an extra js file, rather then editing their application logic used to generate the menus

another option is to use a frame and put your app/link at the top and everything else in inside a frame, but that might not look how you want

Comment: any ideas on what I can do to find the .jsp for html..? I know the name and I have searched the entire program files and folder but can not find it...